# php IIS Windows Server 2008 DateTime Internal Server Error

Tags: php, datetime

I'm hosting my site on a Windows Server 2008 R2. I would like to assign a new DateTime to an object property. The constructor has no params. Everytime i try i get a non specific error called "500 Internal Server Error". If i use Exceptions, it prints the error code "-3" to the page. I don't know why but a error message is not available.

I also tried this [DateTime format issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237765/datetime-format-issue-in-iis-7-server) without success.

Here is a sample:

```
$stop->Arrive_Time          = new DateTime();
```

Comment: Well, you need to either enable error reporting or find the server's logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ini-file described the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Paris' for '1.0/no DST' instead' in ...

solution: [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) in front of all DateTime constructs or objects.