# Web API date issue after publishing in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have been facing the issue in IIS after publishing seems there was a issue in date format.(dd/mm/yyyy)

**Local before publishing**

```
http://localhost:50509/Api/booking?bookingDate=01/11/2016&facBookID=0&isFacBook=Y
```

It returns NOV 1st record.but after publishing this one returns JAN 11th records.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: probably has to do with culture settings on machine. use yyyy-MM-dd to avoid confusion

Comment: we are calling the api  through mobile using this format (dd/mm/yyyy) we could not able to get it right..can you please tell me the solution @Nkosi

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Are you able to change format?

Comment: This dd/mm/yyyy date format which i used to call from mobile app..so i have decided to use same format as well.@Nkosi

Comment: Using that format will cause the problems you are getting. reformat the date to use yyyy/MM/dd.

Comment: Probably because the culture of your iis is different than the one on your local machine. You can force your culture to the one you want on your global.asax file

Comment: unfortunately i have published on same machine @Stormhashe

Comment: Even so, your iis culture might be different than your culture on asp net's development environment. try forcing it on global.asax, it should work

Comment: I have already added this on global.asax **CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
            newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;** @Stormhashe

Comment: Try this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237765/datetime-format-issue-in-iis-7-server    and just change the server settings without any code change.